# Use OpenOffice Uno CLI with C# to create a spreadsheet

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, uno

I have so far found a couple of sources that discuss creation of ODS files: [How to create ODS documents in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117395/how-to-create-ods-documents-in-net) and
[How to create .odt files with C#.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223777/how-to-create-odt-files-with-c-net/4743168#4743168)

And most interestingly [an explanation for opening calc files](http://www.suite101.com/content/creating-an-openoffice-calc-document-with-c-a124112). However this opens OpenOffice in fullscreen, what im looking for is some way to write to a Calc file (.ods) without actually opening Openoffice. So that I can write a function that just opens a savefiledialog, gets the filename and then creates and saves the .ods file.

Are there is any C# code examples available to do such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I have finally resolved this issue and want to save others the hazel of going through this again. Basic points of *HEADACE* for me were:

1. Use **forward slashes** instead of backward slashes (e.g. its `C:/` not `C:\` )
2. The `Filtername` used should be set to the engine used to save the document. Possible values include `writer8`, `calc8`, `MS Excel 97`, so for spreadsheets you obviously need to use **calc8**
3. If you dont want that OpenOffice pops up in the forground and wait for it to get filled with your data, then use the `PropertyValue` and  set `Hidden` to `true`.

Happy coding and dont forget to install the OpenOffice SDK to be able to add the unoidl references:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.uno;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.lang;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.frame;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.beans;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.container;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.table;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.text;

namespace TimeScanner {
    class ReportGenerator {
        private const string fileName = 
            @"file:///C:/Documents and Settings/My Documents/Hours Report.ods";

        //Concrete Methods
        internal XComponent openCalcSheet() {
            XComponentContext oStrap = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
            XMultiServiceFactory oServMan = (XMultiServiceFactory)oStrap.getServiceManager();
            XComponentLoader desktop = (XComponentLoader)oServMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
            string url = @"private:factory/scalc";
            PropertyValue[] loadProps = new PropertyValue[1];
            loadProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
            loadProps[0].Name = "Hidden";
            loadProps[0].Value = new uno.Any(true);
            //PropertyValue[] loadProps = new PropertyValue[0];
            XComponent document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 0, loadProps);
            return document;
        }

        public void writeToSheet(XComponent document) {
            XSpreadsheets oSheets = ((XSpreadsheetDocument)document).getSheets();
            XIndexAccess oSheetsIA = (XIndexAccess) oSheets;
            XSpreadsheet sheet = (XSpreadsheet) oSheetsIA.getByIndex(0).Value;
            XCell cell = sheet.getCellByPosition( 0, 0 ); //A1
            ((XText)cell).setString("Cost");
            cell = sheet.getCellByPosition( 1, 0 ); //B1
            cell.setValue(200);
            cell = sheet.getCellByPosition( 1, 2 ); //B3
           cell.setFormula("=B1 * 1.175");
        }

        public void saveCalcSheet(XComponent oDoc) {        
            PropertyValue[] propVals = new PropertyValue[1];
            propVals[0] = new PropertyValue();
            propVals[0].Name = "FilterName";
            propVals[0].Value = new uno.Any("calc8");
            ((XStorable)oDoc).storeToURL(fileName, propVals);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I installed the SDK but cannot find the references for unoidl.com.sun.star.lang (and others)